# Reference count index in another module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using Terraform modules to create two EC2 instances and assign them with subnets.
I am also using modules.

```
module/network:
resource "aws_subnet" "web_subnet1" {
  count = 2
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.web_vpc.id
  cidr_block  =   cidrsubnet(var.network_cidr, 2, count.index)
  availability_zone = element(var.availability_zones, count.index)
}

output "aws_subnet_web1_id" {
  value = aws_subnet.web_subnet1[*].id
}
```

main.tf file containing the referenced aws_subnet_web1_id

```
module "ec2"{
     source  =   "./modules/ec2"
     aws_subnet_web1_id = module.network.aws_subnet_web1_id
```

Issue is when i am trying to use those subnet id's in the ec2 module to create two ec2 instances:

```
resource "aws_instance" "web1" { 
  count = 2
  ami           = "${lookup(var.ami_ids, "us-west-2")}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

 subnet_id     = "${element(aws_subnet_web1_id[*].id, count.index % length(aws_subnet_web1_id[*].id))}"

}
```

I am getting the bellow error:

```
│ Error: Invalid reference
│ 
│   on modules/ec2/ec2.tf line 11, in resource "aws_instance" "web1":
│   11:  subnet_id     = "${element(aws_subnet_web1_id[*].id, count.index % length(aws_subnet_web1_id[*].id))}"
│ 
│ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.
```

If anybody has any ideea it would be very appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest doing here is using `for_each` meta-argument [1] because what would happen if you decided to increase the number of subnets to more than two? So, in the `ec2` module, you would do this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "web1" { 
  for_each      = toset(var.aws_subnet_web1_id)
  ami           = lookup(var.ami_ids, "us-west-2")
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  subnet_id     = each.value

}
```

Here you would use `toset` built-in function [2] to convert a list to a set. This is possible because the output you are getting from the network module is already a list.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each

[2] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/toset

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to test this. It worked perfect, thank you very much.